# Line read in a loop from a file doesn't assign properly in batch program

Tags: batch-file

I am reading each line of a .txt file in a .batch program using **For /f** loop. The .txt file contains all the names of the test cases (e.g. ***ShipmentPostErrorPathXPERF.txt***) which I need to read and assign to a variable called ***testCaseName*** and pass this to another .cmd program as a parameter and continue in loop until it reads all lines (test cases),

Here is my sample batch file, my problem is when I assign **testCaseName=%%A**, it only shows assigned to the last line of the file (*REST0007-SHIPMETDATA_POST-XPERF_ErrorPath-ShipmentNULLServiceSchedID_TestCase*). But when I use **echo %%A**, it shows all lines as it reads in loop.

Why ***set testCaseName=%%A*** in the batch file only reading the last line ?

.batch file:

```
echo off
cd d:\SWAT
set fileNameXPERF=d:\SWAT\ShipmentPostErrorPathXPERF.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\SWAT\ShipmentPostErrorPathXPERFxxx.txt) do (
set testCaseName=%%A
echo %testCaseName%
echo %%A
call d:\SWAT\testRunner.cmd %testCaseName%
)
```

The text file (ShipmentPostErrorPathXPERF.txt):

```
REST0007-SHIPMETDATA_POST-XPERF_ErrorPath-ShipmentEmptyDockNum_TestCase
REST0007-SHIPMETDATA_POST-XPERF_ErrorPath-ShipmentNULLDockNum_TestCase
REST0007-SHIPMETDATA_POST-XPERF_ErrorPath-ShipmentInvalidDockNum_TestCase
REST0007-SHIPMETDATA_POST-XPERF_ErrorPath-ShipmentEmptyServiceSchedID_TestCase
REST0007-SHIPMETDATA_POST-XPERF_ErrorPath-ShipmentNULLServiceSchedID_TestCase
```

Comment: Hello jeb, my question is not duplicate to 'Variables in batch not behaving as expected'. Can you please let my question be published ?

Comment: Have you even bothered to go through the duplicate question and its answer??

Comment: Sadly, yes. The posting you guys are referring as 'duplicate' doesn't have my answer, that is why I am bothered.